# 2012 V6 Mustang Loses Power when Accelerating

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, acceleration, mustang

I've noticed recently that my 2012 v6 Mustang loses power when accelerating, but only in 4th gear. This happens when I'm getting on the highway since that's the only time I'm accelerating hard in 4th gear. It also clears up if I let off the gas for a second or two then accelerate again.

I've looked up what might be causing this and have already tried cleaning the fuel injectors, the air filter is only a couple hundred miles old, and I plan on replacing the fuel filter next, but I don't think any of that would cause a loss of power in only 4th gear.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!